# Examples on conditional clauses

Tags: conditional-constructions

> When the sun sets, the farmer decides to eat food.
>
> If you go outside you will feel fresh air.
>
> If I walk, I will become fit.
>
> If I sing, my practice becomes more efficient.
>
> If I laugh, I will be happy always.
>
> If I care for you, I will become a responsible citizen.

---

> If you work hard, you will get a pass in the examination.
>       If you sing songs, you will practice efficiently.

---

> If you worked hard, you would get a pass pass in the examination.
>       If you sung songs, you would practice efficiently.

---

> If you had worked hard,you would have passed the examination.
>       If you had sung song,you would have practice efficiently.

I have learned some conditional clauses and after noticing various types and their examples, I decided to make sentences on my own (don't judge me on different types of clauses). Are these sentence grammatically correct?

<strike>Q I want you to notice in these sentences that Are these dependent clauses depends on the main clause and Are these sentence grammatically correct?</strike> (Don't understand, cannot correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects of correctness in those sentences.

First, and we can dispense with it right away, some verbs use the wrong person, wrong form, some nouns are missing necessary articles or pronouns.  Example: When the sun sets, the farmer deside**s** to eat **his** food.  But that aspect is not what you were asking, is it?

Second, and this is the real subject of your inquiry, I think, pretty much all of those sentences use the *correct tenses* and *moods* for subordinate and main clauses.

> If you work hard, you will pass the examination.

becomes (in subjunctive mood)

> If you work**ed** hard, you **would** pass the examination.

So, to answer the main question, yes, most are OK.  I'd watch out for proper verb forms:

> If you <strike>sung</strike> **sang** the song, you would practice efficiently.
>   If you had sung the song, you would have practice**d** efficiently.

Comment: Yes i was not asking for it but extra information is always useful so that i can improve for later examples.

Comment: @Fumble please add the necessary details where you think it might be useful when u made correction.